# eclipse running on mac 32bit

Tags: java, eclipse

i am currently using mac 32 bit.I am unable to open eclipse an error pop up saying that i need to update my JVM from 1.6 to 1.7 and from the java website there are no ver 1.7 for mac 32bit. what am i suppose to do?

Comment: what equipment do you have, and what os x?

Comment: macbook pro running maverick ver 10.9.4 32bit

Comment: Did you try telling Eclipse to use the JVM 1.6 instead? If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use it.

Comment: Mavericks *is* 64-bit—what exactly is preventing the installation of JVM?

Comment: Why do you think you have a 32 bit OS?

Answer (score 2):

Mavericks is a 64-bit OS; it has no 32-bit option... You can run 32-bit apps in it & run 64-bit apps in 32-bit mode, but the OS itself, afaik, is only available in 64-bit.

32-bit Macs cannot run Mavericks.

Edit - 32-bit mode picture...

[image]